# Why does Intellij perform "hg copy" when copying a file?

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial

I noticed that when a file is copied within Intellij it will perform an "hg copy" behind the scenes which is undesirable most (if not all) of the time for my standard uses. Does anyone know the rationale for this behavior? Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: The rationale seems pretty clear: to connect the new file with the history of the original. I don't use intellij so I can't help with the practical part of your question. (But you can always get around the behavior by using _Select All - Copy - Paste_ instead of the file copy function...)

Comment: Generally copying a file (usually a Java class in my use case) does not imply that I want to associate the new file with the history of the old file. It just means I want a new file that is very similar to use as a starting point. I mostly just want the "Select All - Copy - Paste" behavior mentioned by @alexis. I especially do not want changes to the original file to be merged into the new file. I can't think of any case where that behavior would be desirable. I must be missing something.

Comment: @jenglert Have you raised a ticket in YouTrack for this?

Comment: @kierans Nope, haven't submitted a ticket yet as I assumed the behavior was intentional and that I just don't understand the rationale. Should I?

Comment: I think it is a bug, or at least should be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be configurable, as far as I understand, you can have it automatically and silently doing stuff for you, or do nothing, or ask you every time

see for instance https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-version-control-options.html#confirmation